# Find slope of the tangent line of $4\sqrt x + 2e^\frac {3x-12}{x+2}$ at $ x_0$

Tags: calculus, limits, slope

Find the slope and the equation of the tangent line to the
graph $y = f(x)$ at $x_0=4$,  $$4\sqrt x + 2e^\frac {3x-12}{x+2} $$

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\tfrac{4\sqrt {4+h} + 2e^\frac {12+3h-12}{4+h+2} - 10}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{4\sqrt {4+h} + 2e^\frac {3h}{6+h} - 10}{h} $$ I am stuck at this part

Comment: The slope is the derivative evaluated at $x = 4$, but why would you use the limit of the difference quotient definition of derivative to evaluate it?  Is that part of an assigned exercise to carry out this using only the difference quotient limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From where you left by students's L'hospital
$$f'(4)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{2}{\sqrt{4+h}}+2e^{\frac{3h}{6+h}}\frac{3(6+h)-3h}{(6+h)^2}}{1}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{4}}+2.e^0.\frac{3.6}{6^2}=1+1=2$$
and the tangent line at $(4,10)$ is
$$\frac{y-10}{x-4}=2\implies y=2x+2.$$

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using the direct calculus of derivatives, without passing through the incremental ratio.

The equation of the tangent line $r$ at $x = x_0$ for a certain $y = f(x)$ is given by

$$r: f(x_0) + f'(x_0)\cdot (x-x_0)$$

And its slope is just $f'(x_0)$.

The slope is given by $f'(x_0)$ where $x_0 = 4$ in your cases. Thence

$$f(x) = 4\sqrt{x} + 2e^{\frac{3x-12}{x+2}} \longrightarrow f'(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{x}} + 2 e^{\frac{3 x-12}{x+2}} \left(\frac{3}{x+2}-\frac{3 x-12}{(x+2)^2}\right)$$

Or arranging it a bit

$$f'(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{36 e^{\frac{3 (x-4)}{x+2}}}{(x+2)^2}$$

Now it's easy:

$$f'(4) = 2$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{4\sqrt{4+h}-8}{h}+\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{2e^{\tfrac{3h}{6+h}}-2}{h}$$$$=4\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{4+h}-\sqrt4}{h}+2\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^{\tfrac{3h}{6+h}}-1}{h}$$Rationalising the first limit and adjusting the denominator of the second limit, $$ =4\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h}{h\cdot(\sqrt{4+h}+\sqrt4)}+2\times 3\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^{\tfrac{3h}{6+h}}-1}{\frac{3h}{6+h}\cdot (6+h)}$$ Using direct substitution of $h=0$ on the first limit and the formula $\lim \limits_{U\to 0}\dfrac{e^U-1}{U}=1$ on the second limit,$$=4\cdot\frac{1}{2+2}+\frac{2\times3}{6\times 1}=2.$$